# Laravel 5.4 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: laravel

I know that similar topics already exist but none helped me, I have a problem with csrf_token () transfer on global server. At the locallhost everything works, before I added to the global server this application also worked everything, the problem only appeared now and I have no idea what else I can do with it.
Nie mogę wysłać ani jednego formularza w mojej aplikacji, wszędzie używam {{ csrf_field() }}, prubowałem też

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

But that did not change anything. In layouts he uses

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Nie mam pojęcia dlaczego nagle to przestało działać, z góry dziękuję za pomoc.

Comment: Did you generate key by `php artisan key:generate` on your production server?

Comment: I added laravel files to plain hosting, not VPS, I do not have access to the console and I can not install composer or artisan on it so it will not generate a new key on the global server. It's just what I generated on localhost.

Comment: Then you have the answer for your question. Laravel has been not designed for standard hosting (not VPS) and it's very probably that this is the reason why your app is not working. Of course there are some ways to put in on standard hosting, but it is not the proper way.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the quick reply. I took into account that this is one of the possible reasons but I did not think about it because earlier everything was working properly, so I need a dedicated server? On VPS can dump the same error?

Comment: Should a new key be generated when changing the server?

Comment: Yes it should be generated. You don't need a dedicated server. Laravel app on vps will work very well.

Comment: Generating a new key in this case gets nothing further is the same error

Comment: TokenMismatchException